# Jaccard similarity across sets with synonyms

Tags: algorithm, statistics, data-mining, similarity

Supposed you have two users with sets of attributes like so:

```
userA = {"happy", "excited"}
userB = {"sad", "anxious"}
```

Now, if we were to compute the Jaccard similarity of this, it would be 0. However, we want to define that `excited` is pretty similar to `anxious`.

My question is, how can this be structured?

Would I define another set of words that are synonyms to `excited`? How would I then factor this into the Jaccard index computation?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making clusters of synonyms using some sort of thesaurus. Each word would belong to at most one cluster.
For every cluster, choose a "canonical" representative.
Now when you have to compute Jaccard similarity, substitute every word with the representative from its cluster. Then proceed as usual.

Example clusters (representatives marked bold):
1. **Good**, great, excellent, positive, valuable
2. **Bad**, poor, sad, awful

Say you want to compute similarity of two users:
userA = {"positive"}
userB = {"good"}

Then you convert them to
userA' = {"good"} (because "good" is the representative for cluster, which "positive" belongs to)
userB' = {"good"}

Similarity = 1 / 1 = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with words, since they can be ambiguous, but if you were able to derive what WordNet calls "word senses," you could map from that to synsets which would encode all the synonyms which have word senses which match.

See, for example, this Python NLTK example for Word Sense Disambiguation: http://www.nltk.org/howto/wsd.html

Clustering on the synset ID would give the result you want (assuming that `anxious` and `excited` actually have at least one synonymous word sense in the database you're using for disambiguation).